# Linker errors when using Boost Unique pointer with Boost Bind and Boost Function

Tags: c++, boost, unique-ptr, boost-bind, boost-function

Using Boost Bind with a Boost Unique Pointer and Boost Function I am receiving linker errors depending on how I pass a callback to the receiving function.
If I create a Boost Function member variable by binding a callback containing a boost unique pointer param and pass this onto the receiving function, this results in linker errors when attempting to use the unique pointer when the callback is invoked.

If I perform the bind in place when calling the receiving function I do not get the linker errors and the code behaves as expected.

Sample code:

```
class test
{
public:
    test() : callback_(boost::bind(&test::callback, this, _1, _2))

    void start()
    {
        // using boost function pointer,
        // this fails with linker errors
        accept(callback_);                                   // (Method 1)

        // using in place bind
        // this is OK
        accept(boost::bind(&test::callback, this, _1, _2));  // (Method 2)
    }

    void callback(BOOST_RV_REF(boost::movelib::unique_ptr<message>) message,
                  int version)
    {
        // attempting to use message if implemented as (Method 1) will result in linker errors

        message->get_body();  // If I comment out this line then both methods compile and link???
    }

    boost::function
            < void ( BOOST_RV_REF(boost::movelib::unique_ptr < message >) message,
                 int version) > callback_;

};


class callback_tester
{
    callback_tester(){};

    void accept(boost::function
                     < void ( BOOST_RV_REF(boost::movelib::unique_ptr < message >) message,
                          int version) callback)
    {
        // Assignment to local member variable is fine here so we
        // can invoke the callback at a later stage.
        test_callback_ = callback;               

        test_callback_(boost::move(message_), version_);
    }


    // define handler to store and invoke test callback
    boost::function
            < void ( BOOST_RV_REF(boost::movelib::unique_ptr < message >) message,
                 int version) > test_callback_;
    boost::movelib::unique_ptr<message> message_;
    int version_;
};
```

Some of the linker errors are as follows:

```
Error: symbol `_ZN5boost8functionIFvRKNS_6system10error_codeERNS_2rvINS_7movelib10unique_ptrIN5cayan3hal7network10tcp_socketENS6_14default_deleteISB_EEEEEEEED2Ev' is already defined
Error: symbol `_ZN5boost9function2IvRKNS_6system10error_codeERNS_2rvINS_7movelib10unique_ptrIN5cayan3hal7network10tcp_socketENS6_14default_deleteISB_EEEEEEED2Ev' is already defined
Error: symbol `_ZNSt15binary_functionIRKN5boost6system10error_codeERNS0_2rvINS0_7movelib10unique_ptrIN5cayan3hal7network10tcp_socketENS6_14default_deleteISB_EEEEEEvEC2Ev' is already defined
...
```

Can anyone tell me what the difference in the two methods is and why the linker errors only appear when attempting to access the unique pointer when Method 1 is used?

I have come across some information that the callback should be CopyConstructible to use with boost::function.  But if that is true I would have expected both methods to bind and pass a callback containing a unique pointer to fail.

Answer (score 0):

`message` class must have an explicitly declared deleter
at least ~message() = default;